# T50 does not work with docker container

Tags: docker, snort, packet-injection

I'm doing some experiments on **Snort IDS** using **Docker container technology**.

My objective is to test wether snort with the defaults settings can detect **DoS** and **DDoS attacks**.

I downloaded **T50 multi-protocol packet injector** and exectuted it on a container named **T50_container**.

**Snort IDS** is running on another container namend **snort_container**.

The issue is when I run T50 with **T50 --flood a.a.a.a** 
(a.a.a.a is the IP address of snort_container) I'm getting this error message :

error setting socket priority: Operation not permitted.

Thank you for providing me helps and insights.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons a Docker container runs by default with a reduced set of privileges.  This prevents containers from doing things like mounting filesystems and modifying their own network configuration.

You can run a container without these restrictions by specifying the `--privileged` flag to `docker run`:

```
docker run --privileged ...
```

Comment: That worked with --privileged. Thanks again @larsks ;-).